# Custom Camera from 4in to 3.5in programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, camera

I am dynamically creating a custom camera overlay view. It's a class of UI image picker controller.

The Problem: It is currently set up for an iPhone 5/5s, 4in screen, and I'm trying to use auto resizing masks to adjust the entire overlay view and its sub views for a 3.5in screen for iPhone 4/4s. How can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

To edit autoresizing masks programmatically, use `UIView`’s `autoresizingMask` property.